# Ii can't use function in features2d.hpp in opencv

Tags: opencv

I want to use functions in features2d.hpp I know they are nonfree but still I want to use them .
How can I use them please help me .
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

YOu have to include also nonfree.hpp

```
#include<opencv2/nonfree/nonfree.hpp>
```